# How to Extract an apk file from app budle?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am currently able to install the release apk from app bundle to a connected device using the BundleTool. Is there a way to extract the apks from the .apks zip so that I can share it with someone to run on its device. I also tried to get apk from a json configuration file as mentioned in the Bundletool utility but I am getting one base apk and few other apks so how should I go for installing it on a remote device. I tried installing base apk  and the app crashed when I launched the app.

**So basically I need to know how can I extract an apk from an app bundle without having to connect the device.**

Comment: I think it is impossible because you are not generating app-bundle as the same way you generate .apk files. Also, after you edit an .apk file with RAR-reader files to serve to another place, it will not work because you have to compile all of the codes and the files. So, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can check bundle tool [click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool)

For Debug apk command,

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

For Release apk command,

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
--ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks
--ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd
--ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias
--key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd
```

Comment: That I already did as mentioned in the question summary. Problem is little different so please go through the question description again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer but was late to post it. So its a small addition to the answer mentioned by @Emad.

--mode=universal

This will general a universal APK with all the modules included, the size of the build will be high but now the build can be shared without having the device being connected.